# How can I get relations between polygons on a postgres openstreetmap db?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, openstreetmap

I created an openstreetmap db using `osm2pgsql`. It creates some tables, one of these tables is **planet_osm_polygons**.

Other tables created by osm2pgsql are (no foreign keys are created):

- planet_osm_line
- planet_osm_nodes
- planet_osm_point
- planet_osm_polygon
- planet_osm_rels
- planet_osm_roads
- planet_osm_ways
- spatial_ref_sys

Is there any way to get the relations between these polygons?

E.g. for germany I can find the polygon **Bayern**. I would like to get it's parent polygon, in this case **Germany**.

I know that you can find it by using `st_contains`. Is there any other way of doing it?
If there is no other solution I will have to create these relations on my own (which takes some time), but maybe there exists something which I am missing.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the structure of the `planet_osm_polygons` table? Does it have any foreign key constraints?

Comment: no foreign key constraints, the only thing it has is the way column, which holds the geometry, with which i could get the relation to other geometries but that is time consuming

Comment: Are you open to creating the relations on their own? Given the structure of the table, it seems like this is necessary.

Comment: Yes I am open to create the relations on my own, I just hoped there is another way of doing it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the resulting postgres table structure generated by osm2pgsql. However in OSM the relation for Germany has a reference to all federal states, they are contained as members with type `subarea`. There is no reference from federal state relations back to the Germany relation, though.

Comment: true, but I want to get all the relations between the polygons, and not all relations are stored by osm2pgsql as far as I can see

Comment: for the ones who are interested: now, I am using nominatim with some small modifications.

Comment: You can find all related information in `osm_planet_rels` table, `parts` and `members` columns. Not straightforward, but works quite well. Based on `_rels` table I used to get the highway surface for bicycle network.